# Laravel Serviceprovider $this->loadViewsFrom doesn't load blade view wright from package

Tags: laravel-5

I am creating a `Composer` package, beginner
Via `Composer` I have added my package to test application.

The test application output should be `12345`, but instead it prints view name

What is wrong?

DownloadsServiceProvider:

```
class DownloadsServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/resources/views/download', 'downloads');

    public function register()
    {
        new Routes();
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
namespace xxx\xxx\downloads;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DownloadsController
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $test='12345';
        return View('downloads::test' ,compact('test'));
    }
}
```

Route:

```
public function registerRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix(self::CMSURL)->group(function () {

        Route::get(
            '/downloads',
            function (Request $request) {
                //return (new DownloadsController())->index($request)->name(self::DOWNLOADS_LISTER);
                return (new DownloadsController())->index($request);
            }
        );

    });
}
```

View:

```
{{$test}}
12345
```

Output source:

```
downloads::test
```

Comment: Try to replace `View` with `view` (with lowercase first letter) in `return View('downloads::test' ,compact('test'));` line

Comment: @SergeyLebedev nope doesn't work, same result.

Comment: Found it, return in the Routes() (new DownloadsController())->index($request)->name(self::DOWNLOADS_LISTER);  was the problem ->name(self::DOWNLOADS_LISTER). If i remove it it works. So now have a look how i can kae it work